# Thorntail not exiting gracefully

Tags: maven, thorntail

I'm running a Thorntail 2.2.1.Final microservice with Maven using either of these commands

```
mvn thorntail:start
mvn thorntail:run
```

It runs fine, but when I hit `Ctrl-C` it doesn't exit the application i.e. the console returns, but the app runs in the background. I've tried to stop it

```
mvn thorntail:stop
```

But that doesn't work. I have to go and kill the process. I'm using Windows 10.

Comment: The `thorntail:start` and `thorntail:stop` goals are meant to be used together as part of a Maven lifecycle, typically for integration testing. That is, `thorntail:start` intentionally leaves the process running in the background, and `thorntail:stop` should stop it.

For interactive use, `mvn thorntail:run` should be used. That keeps waiting in the foreground, and Ctrl+C should stop the application behind it.

If none of that works, it's a bug. I'd recommend filing a bug in http://issues.jboss.org/browse/THORN and preferrably also include a `jstack` output for the process.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation on stop and start, that wasn't clear to me in the documentation.

Comment: If this was all that you needed, should I copy the comment to an actual answer so that you can mark the question as answered?

Comment: @Ladicek yes, sounds good to me

Comment: Just did that, thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `thorntail:start` and `thorntail:stop` goals are meant to be used together as part of a Maven lifecycle, typically for integration testing. That is, `thorntail:start` intentionally leaves the process running in the background, and `thorntail:stop` should stop it.

For interactive use, `mvn thorntail:run` should be used. That keeps waiting in the foreground, and Ctrl+C should stop the application behind it.

If none of that works, it's a bug. I'd recommend filing a bug in https://issues.jboss.org/browse/THORN and preferrably also include a `jstack` output for the process.

Comment: I'm running Thorntail 2.3.0.Final on Windows 7 and Ctrl+C is not enough to exit Thorntail. It seems that only the .bat file finishes (judging by the confirmation asked). The Java process keeps running.

Comment: Same situation for me with Thorntail 2.4.0.Final on Windows 10. Did you ever open a ticket about it?

Comment: Don't know on Unix, but on Windows Thorntail behaves very bad

Comment: On Linux Thorntail uberjar cannot be stopped via Maven: thorntail:stop is not usable from the CLI

Comment: `thorntail:stop` is not meant to be used from CLI and definitely isn't supposed to stop arbitrary Thorntail uberjars. It's only meant to be used from Maven, in the `post-integration-test` phase, together with `thorntail:start` in the `pre-integration-test` phase.