# Thorntail run goal

Tags: maven, wildfly-swarm, thorntail

I've seen command `mvn thorntail:run` in the documentation, but I cannot find this `run` goal specified in the pom files of provided examples.

Is there run goal at all?

Also I have a problem running my applications this way on Windows since java process is not shut down when I break execution in the console via Ctrl+C. I've read about this problem, but is there any solution to this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Thorntail not exiting gracefully](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53258699/thorntail-not-exiting-gracefully)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is very similar to an existing question. This answer should be good for you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53276378/742081

Comment: Ok, thanks for the answer. Still, is run command realized as maven goal? Also, as it seems like a bug, is there any solution to this?

Comment: And how comes we can execute maven goal if it is not declared in the pom file?

Comment: Yes, `thorntail:run` is a Maven goal. Running a Maven goal that isn't declared in the POM is a standard Maven feature.